# How to set cookies timeout using Owin authentication for frontend and backend

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a project using ASP NET MVC 5 which consists of 2 parts: backend and frontend. I use OWIN authentication. How can I set the cookies timeout separately for the frontend and backend?

Currently, I just only set timeout for entire site.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/LoginAdmin"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, string>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),

                        getUserIdCallback: (claim) => claim.GetUserId())
            },
            ExpireTimeSpan=TimeSpan.FromHours(4)
        });
```